# Display backend log messages in Plotly Dash

Tags: python, logging, plotly-dash

I am currently using Plotly Dash to develop a dashboard for a JVM-based (Kotlin) service. Essentially, the JVM service pushes messages (through ZMQ) to my Python Dash script, which in turns updates a series of live charts.

More than the charts, I would also like to display the service's log messages in the Dash dashboard (they are currently displayed in a console and written to a file). I can easily modify the JVM app/Python script to send/receive the messages through ZMQ, but I haven't been able to find a Dash component that could display those messages in real time.

Since there is a pretty high throughput of messages (a few dozens per second), I would like to be able to filter messages by level (info, warning, etc...) and maybe other criteria (a regex would be ideal). I read the Dash documentation, but wasn't able to find a component that suits my needs. Is there a way to achieve this in Dash?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with how you'd receive the messages in the script, but what you'll want to use is something involving:

- A normal `html.Div(id='log-div',style=dict(height='300px',overflow='auto'))` that is just an empty div that is scrollable
- a `dcc.Interval` that triggers grabbing new logs every n seconds
- A callback function that looks something like

```
@app.callback(
  Output('log-div','children'),
  [Input('log-interval','n_intervals')],
  [State('log-div','children')]
)
def log_content(n_intervals,old_logs):
    # take in the messages through some function
    messages = receive_messages_function()

    # filter the messages here
    messages = filter_messages_function()

    # old_logs is a list of the old messages, with each line being a 
    # separate div (to separate the messages, this can be done in many different ways).
    # So what you do is add the new filtered messages to the old filtered messages
    # Note - this assumes the messages are in a list of some sort; it doesn't matter
    # as the concept is the same - just add the new messages after the old ones
    messages = old_logs + messages

    return messages
```

NOTE - old response was incorrect.

Hope this helps! Comment with any questions/feedback and I'm happy to respond.

Comment: Thank you! I'll have a look at it ;)

Comment: I am not sure this still works in the current version. I receive the following exception upon the start: ``dash.exceptions.SameInputOutputException: Same output and input: log-div.children``

Comment: You're right this never would have worked. It should have been a State rather than an Input. The example given should work now

Answer (score 0):

Even though @russellthehippo their solution looks good, the following example might be a bit more complete. First, you add the following two elements to your `app.layout`:

```
dcc.Interval(id='interval-component', interval=1000, n_intervals=0)
html.Div(id="log-display", style={"whiteSpace":"pre-wrap", "padding-top":"15px", "height":"100%", "overflow":"auto"})
```

... and you define a variable `log_messages` that holds the messages:

```
log_messages = deque(maxlen=10)
```

Notice that the `interval` parameter is in ms. After this, we define the callback function that is activated each time the `interval-component` fires:

```
@callback(
    Output("log-display", "children"),
    Input("interval-component", "n_intervals")
)
def update_log_display(n_intervals):
    log_texts = "\n".join(log_messages)
    return log_texts
```

The last thing is that we need a function that adds the messages to `log_messages`. We define:

```
def add_log_message(message):
    log_messages.append(message)
```

Every time you want to add a new message to the log you can now do:

```
add_log_message("My log message!")
```

... and they will appear in your log element.